# Change the case of letters in the string without built-in functions

Tags: javascript

Write a function that searches the string (passed as first argument) for the
character (passed as second argument) and changes the case for all
instances of that char found in string. Using Built-in functions is prohibited. How to fix it?

```
 function changeCaseOfLetter(text, character) {

    let output = "";
    for(let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {

        if(text[i] === character) {
       let charCode = text.charCodeAt(i);

       if(charCode >= 65 && charCode <= 90) {
            output += String.fromCharCode(charCode + 32);
       }
       if(charCode >= 97 && charCode <= 122) {
           output += String.fromCharCode(charCode - 32);
       }
       if(charCode < 65 || charCode > 122) {
           output += text[i];
       }
    }
    else {
        output += text[i];
    }
}
    return output;
}
```

[image]

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Simple answer: it is not possible to do this without using built-in functions: `String.prototype.charCodeAt` and `String.fromCharCode` are both built-in functions.

Comment: Jeez...what kind of assignment is this? Do you have to write your own javascript languages to avoid of using "built-in" functions? Anyway, what's the issue with that code?

Comment: There is a one of functions that we need to write without any built-in functions. It is mentioned in requirements of the assignment @vanowm

Comment: Guys, I added a screen with a module test results, and you will see what happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited to note:** Having tested your code, it works. Or at least, works according to the problem statement:

> Write a function that searches the string (passed as first argument) for the character (passed as second argument) and changes the case for all instances of that char found in string

So, I would imagine that for that first failing unit test, the test itself is broken, not your code. Executing `changeCaseOfLetter('bRA', 'a')` **should** return `bRA` as the source string contains no lowercase `a` letters.

But if you are actually prohibited from using library functions (and `string.charCodeAt()` and `string.fromCharCode()` are manifestly library functions), fall back to the way library writers have been doing this sort of thing since the days of assembly language: code up a lookup table.

```js
function toggleCase( s , target ) {
    let r = '';
    for (const c of s ) {
        r += c === target   // If the current char matches the target char,
           ? toggle[c] || c // - look it up in the map or fall back to the current char,
           : c ;            // - otherwise, leave it as-is
    }
    return r;
}

const toggle = {
    'A':'a' , 'B':'b' , 'C':'c' , // 'D'–'W' mappings to lowercase omitted for brevity
    'X':'x' , 'Y':'y' , 'Z':'z' ,
    'a':'A' , 'b':'B' , 'c':'C' , // 'd'–'w' mappings to uppercase omitted for brevity
    'x':'X' , 'y':'Y' , 'z':'Z' ,
}
```

This is fairly painless for US-ASCII, but if you need to support Unicode, the problem space rapidly becomes **much** bigger.

**Another little edit:** A little refactoring of your code into much simpler functions that each do one thing can make your code much easier to understand, and much easier to test.

5 minutes of refactoring your code gives me the following. Everything does one simple thing, so easy to test. More importantly, it's easier to understand because the small, simple functions are named with *intent*:

```
function changeCaseOfLetter(text, character) {
    if (!isUpper(character) && !isLower(character) ) {
        throw new Error(`ERROR: '${character}' must be an upper- or lower-case character`);
    }

    let output   = "";
    const toggle = isUpper(character) ? toLower
                 : isLower(character) ? toUpper
                 :                      c => c
                 ;

    for (const c of text ) {
        output += c === character ? toggle(c) : c ;
    }

    return output;
}

const isUpper = c => c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z';
const isLower = c => c >= 'a' && c <= 'z';

const toLower = c => isUpper(c) ? shift(c, +32 ) : c ;
const toUpper = c => isLower(c) ? shift(c, -32 ) : c ;

const shift = (c,distance) => String.fromCharCode( c.charCodeAt() + distance ) ;
```

Comment: You do realize this is a school assignment, it doesn't have to practical, short and support unicode? They test your ability to understand the subject. You went too deep and made it more confusing that it should be...

Answer (score -1):

Since this is your school assigment, I'm not going to post the actual answer, but just a tip.

The problem with your function it only works if both letters are the same case. It's because of this condition: `text[i] === character`

So what you need is convert either of the letters (not both) to capital AND lower case and compare them too. So at the end you'll need 3 different conditions: both letters match, one converted to lower matches or one converted to capital matches. If any of them is true, than proceed with conversion.

Comment: Yeah, but I can not use toLowerCase() or toUpperCase() functions

Comment: Your function converts them somehow, so use the same principle for the conditions.

Comment: That's not the problem.

Comment: @NicholasCarey says who? Once the initial condition passes, the conversion works just fine.